# Complications when upgrading from ASP MVC 3 Preview 1 to beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have just upgraded my ASP MVC 3 application from the preview to the beta version.
In preview everything worked fine, but as soon as I upgraded weird things started to happen.

I get this error message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'Helpers' does
>   not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Source File:  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1512250b\962d050c\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.kncxiw31.0.cs    Line: 19

I have tried to completly rebuild the application, and to clear the temporary asp.net files, but nothing works. My solution builds successfully, no errors while building. But when i try to open the website, I get this error.

These are my referenced dll's:

[image]

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you publishing the site or running it with an attached debugger?

Comment: Right now im running it with a debugger, but im planning on publishing it.

Comment: I have also tried to uninstall both ASP MVC 2 and 3, and then reinstalled only ASP MVC 3 using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After intense searching I found some answers in the [ASP.NET MVC 3 release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes). There is a section called **Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3** which tell you what to do:

Add the two following lines into your `<assemblies>` section in your `web.config`:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had the exact same problem. I resolved it at the time by creating a new project and simply importing all my source code into it.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you need to set the Copy Local property to true on the System.Web.Helpers reference.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the System.Web.Mvc assembly points to the correct version:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

and that System.Web.Helpers also:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll
```

In Beta 3, [`System.Web.Helpers`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0abac7a3-b302-4644-bd43-febf300b2c51&displaylang=en) is a separate download so make sure you've installed `AspNetWebPages.msi`.

Comment: Thank you, but my System.Web.Mvc points to `c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll` and System.Web.Helpers point to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Helpers.dll`. So it looks fine too me, but i'll try to reinstall the `AspNetWebPages.msi` package.